# pd.read_json() returning dataframe with 1 column

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-3.7

Currently I'm trying to load a json file from a webscrape into python in order to search reorder some of the columns, remove some text such as the (\n), etc. I'm having some issues with the json file, the pd.read_json() works (kinda). It returns a dataframe with 1 column titled 'Default'. My current code is below and runs without errors.

I tried the native JSON interpreter but due to some stylized characters and I receive an error.

```py
def main():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df = pd.read_json(file_path)
    print(df)
```

Json file is valid and formatted as so:

```
{
    "Default": [{
        "ItemID": "11111",
        "Title": "A super captivating title",
        "Date": "July 22, 2019",
        "URL": "www.someurl.com",
        "BodyText": "some text."
    }, {
        "ItemID": "22222",
        "Title": "Even more captivating title",
        "Date": "July 12, 2019",
        "URL": "www.differenturl.com",
        "BodyText": "different text"
    }]
}
```

Now I understand that the "Default" is being interpreted as the JSON object and why it's using it as the column. I experimented with several different orients of the read_json() but received more or less the same result.

I'm hoping to have ItemID, Title, Date, URL, and BodyText be the columns and their values being appropriately designated into rows. Any help is appreciated, I couldn't find a similar question but if it has been answered before please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `read_json` orient that will do it. What you need is to pass the `"Default"` content to the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('temp.txt') as fh:
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.load(fh)['Default'])
```

Comment: That did it, thank you so much and sorry for my ignorance with the json.load() .